# how can i split the values of a masked text box in c#

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

I have a masked textbox which dispalys time.I want to get the hour and minute of the time in two seperate variables.
how can i do this.
I have tried something like this.

```
float m = maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart;
MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
```

Comment: What is the mask of the MaskedTextBox? Are you using data binding to bind the text box value to a DateTime variable?

Comment: You could use split on your separator and assign the result to two variables

Comment: Try with `String.Split`...

Comment: got the answer,thanku all                                                      string[] arr = maskedTextBox1.Text.Split(':');
                int hours = int.Parse(arr[0].ToString());
                int mins = int.Parse(arr[1].ToString());

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard mask `00:00`, you can split the string using the `:` separator, like this:

```
string text = maskedTextBox1.Text;
string[] parts = text.Split(':');
try
{
    int hour = int.Parse(parts[0]);
    int minute = int.Parse(parts[1]);
    MessageBox.Show("Hour=" + hour + " minute=" + minute);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input\n" + ex.Message);
}
```

Or, if you prefer exception-free parsing, you can use this:

```
string text = maskedTextBox1.Text;
string[] parts = text.Split(':');
if (parts.Length == 2)
{
    bool successHour, successMinute;
    int hour, minute;
    successHour = int.TryParse(parts[0], out hour);
    successMinute = int.TryParse(parts[1], out minute);
    if (successHour == true && successMinute == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hour=" + hour + " minute=" + minute);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be much better to use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` and check for the boolean result instead of handling the exception?